# Trigger VBA macro as soon as data validation drop down list is opened?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to trigger a macro as soon as a data validation drop down list is opened? (not selecting any value)

Comment: That is pretty much when the cell is selected isn't it?

Comment: @Jeeped , it's not really. Clicking the little Data Validation handle doesn't trigger the Selection_Change event. And selecting a cell doesn't trigger the Data Validation dropdown.

Comment: This isn't quite what you want, but may be of interest: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Excel VBA does not have an event that triggers when a data validation drop-down is merely opened. The closest Excel VBA events would be the

- Worksheet_Change event, which could be set to trigger when a value from such a data validation drop-down is selected, or the
- Worksheet_SelectionChange which would trigger when a cell is selected. The event code can narrow down if the desired cell has been selected, but any code would run merely upon cell selection, not waiting for the data validation drop-down  to be engaged.

Comment: Yeah, Im aware of those. But just wanted to make sure if any event exists in between those two actions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Onur did you ever figure this out?